# How to create and utilize the Vancouver style in specific case?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm supposed to do a bibliography according to the Vancouver style available in BibTeX. I've been given the following reference and I've been told it's based on the Vancouver style:

> Seward JP. Occupational stress. In: LaDou J, editor. Current occupational & environmental medicine.3rd edition. New. York: MC Grow Hill, 2004;p:603-18.

How do I write the reference using the existent entry fields? For example, what does the "In:" mean and what is it's correspondence field in the Vancouver style and how does it gets created?

I've been searching for the aforementioned reference and looks like I can't find it on the internet! Please let me know how may I "LaTeX"ize these kinds of references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the manual at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/vancouver?lang=en with example `.bib` file, this looks like an `@InBook` entry.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you very much, Please add your comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `@incollection` entry type for this entry.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@incollection{seward:04,
  author    = "James P. Seward",
  title     = "Occupational Stress",
  editor    = "Joseph LaDou",
  booktitle = "Current Occupational \& Environmental Medicine",
  publisher = "McGraw-Hill",
  edition   = "Third",
  year      = 2004,
  pages     = "603-618",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\begin{document}
\nocite{seward:04}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```